# Change color of a Flex 4 spark Button

Tags: button, flex4, flex-spark

Is there an easy way to change the background color of a Flex 4 spark Button without messing with skins?

***UPDATE***: ok, figured it out, simply set the `chromeColor` attribute of the Button mxml.

Answer (score 6):

For spark components, you can use **chromeColor** style:
    `<s:Button chromeColor="0xff0000" label="chrome red"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `color` style of the button. You can also have a bitmap fill.

**Update**: The above methods do not change the background.

Easiest way to change the background, you can use - `opaqueBackground` property.

Here is another way to change the background of a button without changing its skin -
1. Create a group with a rectangle and your button.
2. Set `opaqueBackground` of your button to null.
3. Make `width` and `height` of rectangle to `100%`
4. whatever color you fill the rectangle with is the background of your button.

Comment: How do I change the color style?  If I do <s:Button label="This text will be blue, but not the background" color="#0000FF"/> it just changes the Label, not the background.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done via code like :-

```
btnID.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, textChange);
btnID.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, textChangeback);

private function textChange(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnLinkDelete.setStyle("color", 0xFFFFFF)
    btnLinkDelete.setStyle("chromeColor", 0x535151)
}

private function textChangeback(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnLinkDelete.setStyle("color", 0x000000)
    btnLinkDelete.setStyle("chromeColor", 0xfcffff)
}
```

I am posting it, if anyone want to change background color on mouse hover.